# Android OpenStreetMap allow users to download a map

Tags: android, android-studio, maps

My app is using the open street map API, and while it works fine online, a big portion of its use will most likely have people using it in areas without internet. What I want is for people who know they won't have internet, to be able to download the map they will need(say a city) and use it. Is this possible with Open street maps?